# How I can validate the form with another method like asynchronous methods(promises or async-await)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, validation, asynchronous

How I can validate the form below with another method like asynchronous methods(promises or async-await)?

In the form below, the form is validated if onsubmit ="return validateForm()" is equal to the boolean true and it is not validated if onsubmit ="return validateForm()" is equal to the boolean false.

My problem is : the asynchronous functions always  return promises, and don't return boolean value...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello Javascript</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         function validateForm()  {
             var u = document.getElementById("username").value;
             var p = document.getElementById("password").value;

             if(u== "") {
                 alert("Please enter your Username");
                 return false;
             }
             if(p == "") {
                 alert("Please enter you Password");
                 return false;
             }

             alert("All datas are valid!, send it to the server!")

             return true;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>

      <h2>Enter your Username and Password</h2>

      <div style="border:1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;">
         <form method="POST" action="process-action.html" onsubmit = "return validateForm()">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
            <br><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name = "password" id="password"/>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation code you wrote is synchronous client side code, and you don't need promises to execute it.

What you need to do here is use `e.preventDefault` because otherwise the submit button will try to trigger a form submit to the server.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted#answer-3350351) as example.

If you take this road, use `e.preventDefault` to prevent triggering the form submit, validate the form and submit it by launching an ajax call instead.